# compile C program in multiple folders

Tags: c, shell, automation

I have a bunch of directories with `C` programs. I need to compile them one by one and use the result in the main Program.

So my Main program traverse in the Directory structure [I am not sure what the structure is, It may change over time] and compiles one `C` program at a time, use that result in some computation.

So If I write the main program in `C` and use [nftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) to traverse.

OR

Write a Shell main program.

Which appraoch is better?

Comment: This is what makefiles are for.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `void*`.

Comment: Please provide an example (sub directories, what is the result you want to reuse into the main program, what's for the main program???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use a compatible Unix/Linux/Cygwin system....
 
Therefore, I would advice to use a shell solution because it is more suitable for directory processing.

### `Makefile` for each program

As @Dogbert said `make` can be used to build several programs. Build can be performed in parallel (using the option `-j`). Moreover `make` can also take care about the dependencies.

I do not know if you are used with `Makefile` syntax. Therefore I give a quick example about a program requiring three `C` files and one header file:

```
program: file1.o file2.o file3.o
    gcc -o -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c header.h
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

The following command will compile `file1.c`, `file2.c` and `file3.c` in parallel. Then link stage will wait for the completion of these tree compilations.

```
make -j3
```

### Directory discovery

The following command finds each `Makefile` and runs the `make` command:

```
find . -name Makefile -exec make -j3 -f '{}' ';' 2>&1 | tee result.txt
```

If you have 8 cores in your computer, you can use `-j8`.

### Reuse in your main program

The build result is displayed on the shell screen and is also stored in the `result.txt` file.

### More information?

I do not know what is your system, or your knowledge. Hope this can help. If you are not sure to understand some parts, please ask for more information. ;-)